# Show different content in custom template for two different menu items in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a menu bar in my header.php. In that menu bar there are two menu items. One is Training and second is Partners. I have created a custom template named two_column.php. I want to use this custom template for this two menu items. They both have different content as well as different sidebar(on right). So, how to achieve that?

Below is my custom template code...i.e two_column.php code......!

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Two Column
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div class="header-clone" style="height: 0px;"></div>
<div id="main" class="clearfix">
    <div class="main-wrapper-item">
        <div class="bread-title-holder">
            <div class="bread-title-bg-image full-bg-breadimage-fixed" style="background-position: 50% -303px;"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="container_inner clearfix">
                        <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <section class="cont_nav">
                            <div class="cont_nav_inner">
                                <p>
                                    <?php my_breadcrumb(); ?>
                                    <!--<a href="http://www.verifasttech.com/">Home</a>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <span class="skt-breadcrumbs-separator"> / </span>
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <span>Training</span>-->
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content default-pagetemp">
            <div class="container post-wrap">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div id="content" class="span8">
                        <div class="post" id="post-3284">
                            <div class="skepost">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <p class="heading">Overview</p>
                                <p> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
                                <p class="heading">Training modules cover the following aspects:</p>
                                <ul style="float: left; width: auto;">
                                    <li>Verification Architecture</li>
                                    <li>Test Bench Development</li>
                                    <li>Test Plan Development</li>
                                    <li>Test Plan Implementation</li>
                                    <li>Transaction Level Modeling</li>
                                    <li>Bus Functional Models</li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul style="float: left; width: auto; margin-left:75px">
                                    <li>Code &amp; Functional Coverage</li>
                                    <li>Verification Sign-off</li>
                                    <li>System Verilog (UVM, OVM, VMM)</li>
                                    <li>SystemC, C/C++, Perl, Specman e, Vera</li>
                                    <li>ASIC, SoC, FPGA (Xilinx &amp; Altera)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p class="heading" style="clear: both;">Training Programs</p>
                                <p>VeriFast offers two verification training programs. An in-depth System Verilog UVM/OVM verification “BootCamp” program for senior verification engineers and a “JumpStart” program for junior engineers. Our training programs are very thorough 4 day to 16 session programs complete with complex lab/practice examples and with state of the art EDA tools.</p>
                                <h2 style="clear: both;">Boot Camp</h2>
                                <p>For senior verification engineers who wish to gain extensive hands-on experience with SystemVeirlog UVM/OVM we offer Boot Camp programs. This program will provide you the knowledge and experience necessary to implement what you learn into real world verification environments fast. Complete our program to avoid many first timer pitfalls.</p>
                                <p class="heading">VeriFast offers following BootCamp training programs:</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>BootCamp : SystemVerilog </li>
                                    <li>BootCamp : UVM (Coming Soon)</li>
                                    <li>BootCamp : SVA (Coming Soon)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <h2>Jump Start</h2>
                                <p>For junior level or new grads who are looking for a edge we offer a 16 session extremely in-depth program. This program is designed to give you a 12 month experience level gain. For employers who wish to have their entry level hires trained prior to starting their new job, this program is perfect. Your new hires will hit the ground running fast without eating up valuable time from team members.</p>
                                <p class="heading">VeriFast offers following JumpStart training programs:</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>JumpStart : ASIC Verification</li>
                                    <li>JumpStart : FPGA Design (Coming Soon)</li>
                                </ul>
                                <p class="heading">Who can Benefit</p>
                                <p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3394" src="http://www.verifasttech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Untitled.png" alt="Untitled" width="258" height="184" align="right"></p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Senior Verification Engineers looking to learn the latest in verification methodologies.</li>
                                    <li>DV Managers looking to implement System Verilog UVM into their verification flow.</li>
                                    <li>DV Managers looking to have their junior engineers trained prior to starting their first day on their new job.</li>
                                    <li>Verification managers who desire to have the junior engineers be more productive.</li>
                                    <li>Junior engineers looking for a competitive edge and who wish to learn more about complex verification.</li>
                                    <li>College Graduates looking to gain entry into the field of Design Verification</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- skepost -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- post -->
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- content -->
                    <!-- Sidebar -->
                    <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
                        <div id="sidebar_2" class="ske_widget">
                            <ul class="skeside">
                                <li id="text-2" class="ske-container widget_text">
                                    <div class="textwidget">
                                        <iframe src="http://training.verifasttech.net/index.html" width="400px" height="610px" autoscroll="no"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- #sidebar_2 .ske_widget -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <!-- Sidebar -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Below is two images for menu item TRAINING & PARTNERS.....

[image: TRAINING]

[image: PARTNERS]